# "The model is probably unidentified" in AMOS - how to fix this?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor, amos

I am trying to fit a second-order factor in AMOS (where 'AA', 'AB', and 'AC' are thought to be facets of the higher-order factor 'AD'). I am getting the error message "Result (Measurement model)
The model is probably unidentified. In order to achieve identifiability, it will probably be necessary to impose 1 additional constraint."

Can anyone advise on how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a second order factor, which is trying to explain the covariances among the first order factors.

But the first order factors are allowed to covary. So there's nothing for the second order factor to do.

Pretend your first order factors are measured variables, and you are fitting a single factor model to it. You wouldn't add covariances.

Comment: I see, thank you!